# Vuejs access function from nested fuction

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to access a function A from  a function in a function in A eg:

```
functionA () {
    functionB () {
        functionC () {
           #want to call functionA from here
        }
     }
 }
```

here is the code I am using:

```
updateProgress: function (statusurl){
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: statusurl,
      dataType: 'json',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
      async: true,
      data: {}
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        var data = response.data
        if (data['state'] !== 'PENDING' && data['state'] !== 'PROGRESS') {
          if ('result' in data) {
            // show result
            console.log('result: ' + data['result'])
          }
          else {
            // something unexpected happened
            console.log('state: ' + data['state'])
          }
        }
        else {
          // rerun in 2 seconds
          setTimeout(function() {
            this.updateProgress(statusurl)
          }, 2000)
        }
      }.bind(this))
      .catch(e => {
        console.log('error: ' + e)
      })
```

As you can see I am using this.functionA from functionC and bind() on functionA.

I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.updateProgress is not a function at eval
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: pretty the `function (response)` binding syntax is wrong anyway. Why don't you just use an arrow function instead i.e. `response =>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the value of `this` has changed. Every time you enter a new function (as declared with the `function` keyword) the value of `this` changes. In this specific case it is the function called by `setTimeout` that is at fault:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    this.updateProgress(statusurl)
}, 2000)
```

In years gone by the solution would be to grab a reference to `this` under a different name:

```
var me = this    

setTimeout(function() {
    me.updateProgress(statusurl)
}, 2000)
```

Slightly less old-school would be using `bind`, like you have for the other nested function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    this.updateProgress(statusurl)
}.bind(this), 2000)
```

If you have ES6 arrow functions available (and judging by your `catch` it would seem you have) then you don't even need to use `bind`. Arrow functions don't change the value of `this` so you can just write:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.updateProgress(statusurl)
}, 2000)
```

Your other use of `bind` can similarly be removed.